# Currently doing the OdinProject course that requires the Oracle Virtual Machine, I let it update then came back to this error :/ TIA

Tags: virtual-machine

[VM error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTKp5.png)

I've tried reinstalling and googling the error code, none of the guides I've tried have worked. Just thought I'd try here, see if anyone else has encountered a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer! After a few failed tutorials stumbled on this comment in stackoverflow relating to a different problem and gave it a go...

"I went to Control Panel > Programs and Feature (or right click Windows logo) then selected Oracle VM VirtualBox(4.3.12) and then hit repair at the top. I restarted then it worked!"

And we're back up and running!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).